# Avoiding two phase initialization

Tags: c++

I've been doing some reading and the general opinion seems to be that two phase initialization is to be avoided where possible. I agree with much of what it said. But I'm not finding it so easy to eliminate.

Here is an entirely made up example, although strongly based on some real code -

Imagine I am building a game. The main game class needs to construct a "RenderDevice" object that does the 3d rendering. But in order to construct this it needs some settings to be loaded from a configuration file. And a Window object to draw into. And a logger object, and a memory pool. My code now puts all of those things as class members where the constructor does little and then calls an init function on each object with the relevant parameters, something like :-

```
// Much simplified code to make a point
Game::Game()
{
    memoryPool_.init(10000000); // Amount of memory to allocate
    logger_.init("logfile.txt", memoryPool_);
    window_.init(2000, 1000);   // Make a nice big window
    renderDevice_.init(window_, logger_, memoryPool_);
}
```

That to me seems to work reasonably well. But it's two phase. Each object is only partially constructed by it's constructor. So I'd have to do something much like this instead to make the code "clean".

```
Game::Game() :
    memoryPool_(1000000),
    logger_("logfile.txt", memoryPool_),
    window_(2000, 1000),
    renderDevice_(window_, logger_, memoryPool)
{
}
```

Now that code seems rather ugly to me, but also rather fragile as the order of initialization depends on the order they are declared in the class, NOT the order listed here. As more data gets added to the class, it gets even worse. The objects here only require a few parameters but if they need more data this will rapidly get out of hand.

It has the advantage that each object is constructed ready to do it's job, but it looks ugly to me and seems rather fragile and error prone...

So my question is have I missed the point? Is there a better way to do this? Should I stop worrying and just do this, or should I use my original code? Or is my whole design wrong at a higher level in some way and so the question isn't useful?

Basically what is best practice?

Comment: I think you are seriously confused.

Comment: The best practice is definitely the one that, for whatever reason I don't understand, you deem ugly and fragile. Fact is, it's much more solid than two-phase initialization (and no uglier).

Comment: @Marcin Hehe I am very confused, this is what comes of reading too much :) Ok, I guess it's not ugly then. I'll try to use it and see how it works :)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I just felt I'd missed something. I knew why the initializer list is objectively better. It just felt *wrong* when I wrote the code. If it's the recommended approach I'll go with it :)

Comment: I would go one step further... the only strict dependency (just blindly guessing) is that the memory pool needs to be initialized before the rest of the elements. I imagine that there is some way of making the window visible and enabling rendering. If that is the case, you can break the dependency on the order of initialization by creating the memory pool externally and passing that to the `Game` constructor. In many cases passing the resources to the constructor (rather than creating them internally) can make things simpler, and much simpler to test.

Comment: The argument against using the initializer list is how to handle API errors/exceptions, but that's really the same problem as doing all that work in the constructor using either method.  What happens if/when one of the setups you're calling fails for some reason?  (This is way old Scott Meyers advice anyways).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Ok, I think I understand what you are saying. I could create some of those object externally to my Game constructor and pass them as parameters.

Comment: @ChrisO Then you just throw an exception from the constructor. If it is too complex to handle that in a single multi-purpose class, then your design is bad anyway and you should split it into several RAII, single-responsibility classes.

Comment: @Syam Fair enough, that is good advice, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 8):

> Now that code seems rather ugly to me

Doesn't look that way to me. Maybe you're just not used to it?

> rather fragile as the order of initialization depends on the order they are declared in the class, NOT the order listed here

Turn on your compiler's warnings, it should tell you about a mismatch between those two orders. (I know Clang has this warning, and I'm pretty sure GCC has it too. Not quite sure about MSVC.)

> The objects here only require a few parameters but if they need more data this will rapidly get out of hand.

I don't see how that is different when you're using `init()`.

Comment: When I use init() I can for example do several lines of code to calculate the parameters to pass to a variable to initialize it, I can't do that in a constructor parameter list. I guess I can still call functions to get the values though.

Comment: Yes, functions are the way to go here. More than minimal value calculation would also really clutter up the init-based constructor body.

Comment: GCC certainly has that warning on by default.

Comment: @jcoder You can use functions, lambdas, a delegate private constructor which parameters are computed by the public constructors, or even a member variable that is initialized first (even though I obviously wouldn't recommend it for transient parameters). You really have a lot of choices.

Comment: Yes, you **can** do several lines of code to calculate a parameter in an initializer list; just put the lines of code into a function and call it!

Comment: You can even use a base mixin constructor, which is called before the first member is initialized. Just add `: public MemoryPoolInitMixin` to the class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience init functions are used in places where there are possible errors and exceptions cannot be used / thrown. The examples you mention all have error cases and seem to be just throwing an exception since there is no return value checked.

I think it's good practice to call a set of inits from an init function in Game rather than calling the inits from the constructor itself.